# Web template does not uploaded in the solution gallery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-template

I have created a web template using the default.aspx,defaultdws.aspx and ONET.xml file from the sts folder. I didn't get any error while deploying but the template doesn't get uploaded in the solution gallery.